# Bash Rename a file

Tags: bash

I have many files in my directory:

```
projet2.tar.gz proj.txt file.png
```

In want to add "_alice" to each file.  projet2_alice.tar.gz proj_alice.txt file_alice.png
Here is my script :

```
#/bin/bash                                                                                
if [ $# = 0 ]                                                                             
then                                                                                      
echo "Erreur:vous devez indiquer le nom de fichier a renommer"                            
fi                                                                                        
echo $1
```

which command i have to use : `rename, sed, mv` ?

Comment: Have you tried any of the commands you mention?... hint: `mv`

Comment: I'm going with _C. Two of the above_... Honestly, you have to show what research you did.

Comment: Your current attempt has a couple of trivial errors. Try http://shellcheck.net/ for diagnosing problems and antipatterns in your shell scripts.

Comment: can i use cut command in this case ? Bests.

Comment: You can use a lot of different commands. Cut would be one of them. But really? Right now you're just outputting your parameter. You will likely need something like a loop or you can probably do this just by using `find` with `-exec`.

Comment: i have used cut and mv. It works now.

Comment: If you were able to solve your own problem you can post an answer below. Next time please show a little bit more effort into solving your problem before asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `prename` (simply `rename` on Debian and derivatives) command. No loop is necessary:

```
rename 's/\./_alice./' *
```

will insert `_alice` before the first dot in the name on all files (`*`).